# Flask-SQLAlchemy returning object in query when working with many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new with SQLAlch and I'm trying to do a simple query in my database but i'm getting objects in response instead of strings. My data model is the following:

```
wallet_tags_association = db.Table(
    'wallet_tags', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('wallet_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('wallet.id')),
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'))
)


class WalletData(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'wallet'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    total_value = db.Column(db.DECIMAL)
    tags = db.relationship('Tags', secondary='wallet_tags')

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class Tags(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_name = db.Column(db.String(20))

    def __init__(self, tag_name):
        self.tag_name = tag_name
```

and the query I'm trying to do is the following:

```
wallet_tags = WalletData.query.join(Tags, WalletData.tags).all()
for u in wallet_tags:
   print(u.tags)
```

And this is what I got after iterating...

```
[<Tags: dividends>, <Tags: value>, <Tags: high yield>]
```

I have tried to follow the SQLAlch docs and there the approach is to use labels. Couldn't find a way to use labels when querying with Models.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your print statement yields a collection of Tag objects related to each WalletData. What are you expecting or looking for?

Comment: @CodeMantle The data I'm getting in return is correct. The problem is that i'm looking to have a list like this: ['dividends', 'value', 'high yield'] withou the Tags reference on it.

Comment: Try `print(u.tags.tag_name)`? You have full 'referential powers' with the relationship attribute.

Comment: Already tried that....it returns `AttributeError: 'InstrumentedList' object has no attribute 'tag_name'`

Comment: ah, that's because it is a many-to-many relationship, and `u.tags` returns an SQLA list of Tags objects. You can iterate through each `u.tags` to get at the constituent mapped Tags objects (`for tag in u.tags: print tag.tag_name`)

Comment: That's it! Bro, thank you very much for your patience and support. Any way to mark your commend as the right answer for my question? You need the get credits for that! hehehe

Comment: I've put in an answer and explanation, if you wish to mark it as the accepted answer. Good luck with further endeavours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The corrected query for this needs to be:

```
wallet_tags = WalletData.query.join(Tags, WalletData.tags).all()
for u in wallet_tags:
   print(', '.join([tag.tag_name for tag in u.tags]))
```

Explanation: There is a many-to-many join between the two main tables (an intermediate table was constructed). The relationship expression on `WalletData` will pick up a list of connected `Tags` objects. Iterating through this collection for each `WalletData` object will yield the desired set of record field names.