# SQLALchemy query to parent relation using child relation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have two models like

**Model 1:**

class ChildDetail(Base):

```
__tablename__ = "ChildDetail"
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
type = Column(Integer, nullable=True, 0)
parent = relationship("Parent", backref="ParentDetails")
```

**Model 2**

class Parent(Base):

```
__tablename__ = "Parent"
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
status = Column(Integer, nullable=True)
```

Now I want to filter on basis of parent status. I just a information about `ChildDetail`

My filter query is something like this

```
 session.query(ChildDetail)
    .filter(ChildDetail.type == 0 ,
            ChildDetail.parent.status == 2)
    .all()
```

issue is here I. can't access  `ChildDetail.parent.status`. I want to filter on basis of parent status.How I can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new to SQLAlchemy but this is how you'll do it I think, let me know if this works for you.

```
session.query(ChildDetail).join(Parent).filter(Parent.status==2).all()
```

This will join both of the tables and filter the query result based on the status of the Parent table.

Comment: not working :( . it's giving some  weird objects not value

Comment: did you include .all()? Try taking a look at this post, it might solve the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65931353/flask-sqlalchemy-returning-object-in-query-when-working-with-many-to-many-relati

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.